# Google Cloud / App Engine - add new custom domain not verified after 6+ days

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a functioning app on Google cloud running at https://abcd-efgh-1234.appspot.com .

After going through the steps to create a new custom domain, the page still shows "Your domain hasn't been verified yet. Finish all the steps in Webmaster Central and then return to this page."

I did follow the steps and create a TXT record on the domain using the supplied key, but the new domain remains unverified on Google Cloud, with no messages, no contact.

Comment: This means that the domain is not verified. Go back, delete the custom TXT record and start over. In my experience the verification takes only a minute or less. The process is automated, as it just reads the TXT record. Tip: make the TTL short for this record so that if you have to change it again, you won't have to wait for the TTL to expire.

Comment: Another tip is use a DNS tool on the Internet to verify that your doman and DNS servers are setup correctly. You can also read the TXT record to make sure that it contains the value that you expect. `dig -t txt example.com`